# Slim Translation error syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, slim-lang

im doing translations to Haml-Slim, i have a problem in this line:

```
modal-alerts data= 'target-url' = new_alert_url.gsub('jusjus.jusjus', 'jusjus'),
            'ajax-form' = "false",
            'btn-ok' = 'off',
            :title = I18n.t('common.get_new_alerts')
```

The error is:

```
_alerts_bar_housing.html.slim:9: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end 'ajax-form' = "false", ^
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I have a problem with this line:      [code]= &nbsp; #{will_paginate @posts, :container => false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modal-alerts data={'target-url' => new_alert_url.gsub('jusjus.jusjus', 'jusjus'), 'ajax-form' => "false", 'btn-ok' => 'off', 'title' => I18n.t('common.get_new_alerts')}
```